# Easiest way to access a xml form variable from java snippet in jsp page?

Tags: java, xml, forms, jsp

Basically, I have an xml form that redirects the user to another webpage. I need the form to also pass in a field that the user enters.

This form redirects the user to a jsp page and I'm using a java scriptlet in the page to create a sql database, but I can't figure out a way to access the user's input in that java scriplet.

Here is the java sciptlet:

```
<jsp:scriptlet><![CDATA[


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", ""); 


stmt = con.createStatement();


stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS new_presidents_db;");
stmt.executeUpdate("use new_presidents_db");
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS new_presidents_db;");
stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS presidents_table;");
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE presidents_table (id INT, presidents_name varchar(50),         PRIMARY KEY (id));");

stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO presidents_table (id, presidents_name) VALUES ('1', 'George Washington')");
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO presidents_table (id, presidents_name) VALUES ('2', 'John Adams')");
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO presidents_table (id, presidents_name) VALUES ('3', 'Thomas Jefferson')");


ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM presidents_table;");
String resultString=null;
Integer i = 1;
while(result.next() && i < 3)
{
resultString=result.getString(i);
out.println(resultString);
i++;
}
con.close();



]]></jsp:scriptlet>
```

What I'd like is to include in the sql select statement, something like, SELECT * FROM presidents_table WHERE id = "user input variable here";

But I have no idea how to access that variable from the form.

I'm somewhat familiar with java but jsp and forms are completely new to me. Anybody know the best way to get this variable from the xml form?

Comment: You really need to read about programming with JSP and Servlets, keeping in mind MVC separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: DO NOT open database connection in your JSP. Do that in some model class and use servlet for communication between JSP and that model class. Basically, use MVC design pattern.

Second: Use `String id = request.getParameter("id");` (in servlet of course) (if your component for input is for example: `<input type="text" name="id">`) to get user input.

Also, have a look at this [PreparedStatement](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) example to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Regards.

Comment: A good overview. Still I think that providing useful links for each topic would be invaluable for OP.

Comment: Yeah...in one hand my answer seems poor, since he obviously have a little or no experience with servlets and jsp's.

Comment: I find your answer a perfect fit to this question (still I'd have made some formatting corrections).